# Redirect to profile page if profile is not completed laravel-5.8

Tags: laravel-5.8

I'm developing a application in laravel 5.8. In my application, I'm try to force redirect a authenticated user to profile page if the user not completed their profile 100%. I have a profile_completed column in users table, where i'm tracking the % of completeness of the profile. So if the user try to go other routes it will redirect them back to profile page again. Here is my routes:

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::group(['middleware' => ['verified']], function() {
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/profile_page', 'HomeController@profilePage')->name('profile_page');
Route::get('/edit_profile', 'HomeController@editProfile')->name('edit_profile');
Route::post('/update_personal_info', 'HomeController@updatePersonalInfo')->name('update_personal_info');
Route::post('/update_business_info', 'HomeController@updateBusinessInfo')->name('update_business_info');
});
```

Now i'm not getting any idea, where and how should i do it. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

After successful login, you have to check for percentage in landing page method and from there you can redirect to  Profile page if the profile is not completed.

Comment: I don't want it only on login, I wanted it for every time a route hits. And i solved the problem using separate middleware.

Comment: for every time on route hits you can check in rout's method for complition percentages and can redirect from that method also.

Comment: Thanks for your time. But i got the solution. Thought i will try your way and let you know